# LinkedIn Api: network/updates gives 403

Tags: ruby, linkedin-api

I'm using [linkedin-oauth2](https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2) gem
to connect with LinkedIn Api. The following snippet gives me 403 error:

```
client = LinkedIn::API.new(user_access_token)
client.profile # works well
client.network_updates # gives 403 error
```

I gave all possible permissions to the app (including rw_nus). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem on LinkedIn side connected with cache. Adding permissions to the existing app doesn't work but creating app with needed permissions gives exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting probably this issue because you are not setting properly the scope for the omniauth gem to request this permissions on the client-side oauth2 besides how the app permissions are configured in the Linkedin developer network site.

Try addind something like

```
:scope => 'r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_emailaddress r_network'
```

to the existing config line you might have in the Omniauth (or Devise) initializer file.

```
provider :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET']
```

Then you should get both Apps working good.

Comment: No, it's not the case. From the beginning i didn't set them properly then added needed permissions and it still didn't work. Creating app with needed permissions (without setting additional permissions later) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permission because linkedin api is changed go through the url for more info http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/recent-changes-in-linkedin-api